# Laptop giving battery issues on dual boot in different disks

Tags: windows, laptop, multi-boot, battery, ubuntu-20.04

For the last year I've been having issues with my experience in both Windows 10/11 and both Ubuntu 20.04. Since the installation of an SSD for W10 and an M.2 for Ubuntu, energy has been the only point that has been giving problems. This didn't happen when I had both OSs in different partitions in the same disk.

Firstly, the charge has randomly been dropping down to 0% and hibernating -passing by GRUB when booting the laptop- since I installed both storage units. It's not 100% that it will do that after turning it on, but even if I charge it at 100% all night, at some point it will just do what I've commented. It specially happens when using Windows: if I power the PC on and choose Windows, and then switch to Linux, it is very likely that it will show 0% and hibernate. It can also happen viceversa, but it won't happen when only using Ubuntu.

Apart from that, it takes around a minute for Ubuntu to realize it's charging (top right battery icon), while on Windows it's right away. This can be an issue specially when I plug the laptop in and trust that it's charging, and suddenly see it has dropped to a 10% and realise the brick is not correctly plugged.

At first I thought the issue could be on the drivers, but it would only affect one OS and I don't think it's about the battery health (a 75% original capacity wouldn't, maybe a 50 or lower one). I don't think the battery is faulty, as it shows around 80% capacity:

```
$ upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               SMP
  model:                L17M3PB1
  serial:               7646
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              lun 02 may 2022 11:31:09 (68 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               charging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              1,34 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         35,56 Wh
    energy-full-design:  45 Wh
    energy-rate:         6,677 W
    voltage:             12,032 V
    time to full:        5,1 hours
    percentage:          9%
    capacity:            79,0222%
    technology:          lithium-polymer
    icon-name:          'battery-caution-charging-symbolic'
  History (charge):
    1651483869  9,000   charging
  History (rate):
    1651483869  6,677   charging
```

I don't really know what to do. It's really painful being in class and suddenly seing that your battery drops to 0% in random moments without any sockets nearby. Any further information will be provided if necessary. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Run the built-in BIOS/UEFI firmware hardware diagnostics _(e.g. BIOS/UEFI firmware boot menu [Diagnostics](https://imgur.com/a/IjOKPHZ))_ Full/Through Test on the battery and charger _(note capacity percentage shown; if different than `upower`, Diagnostic's value would be accurate)_. What this sounds like is a failing/failed battery or charger, as the OS has no control over either - charging is handled by firmware that is OS-independent. To determine which if Diagnostics doesn't show battery capacity ~50% or below, a known good charger/known good battery would need to be used to troubleshoot

Comment: _(Cont'd...)_ Coincidence doesn't equal correlation - SSD's use less power than a mechanical HDD _(they do generate more heat when under load)_ and their standby consumption is in the mW [`V*A=(W*1000)`]. When you boot Windows and switch to Linux, are you sleeping Windows or hibernating it _(sleep keeps everything in RAM, hibernate saves RAM to disk)_? "_...and realize the brick is not correctly plugged_": Does the charger's DC jack have a center pin? If so, this data pin or laptop's DC jack receptacle connection for it could be failing; if so, replacing the laptop's DC jack often fixes this.

Comment: @JW0914 Thanks for your answer.

- My BIOS doesn't have any diagnostics option
- When I boot to the other OS, I previously reboot it or turn it on after it has been turned off for a while (frequently for a couple of hours)
- The DC jack looks like [this one](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41ozqZu+0dL._SL500_.jpg)

Comment: AFAIK, every laptop comes with built-in BIOS/UEFI diagnostics _(manual/OEM support site may need to be consulted; usually it's available from the BIOS/UEFI firmware boot option page or from within the BIOS/UEFI firmware settings)_. Since the DC jack isn't the older style with a communication center pin, likely issue is a failing/failed battery _(it could be a bad power brick, but battery is more likely)_. Laptop batteries are only good for ~200 charge/discharge cycles when charged to 100%, ~400 if charged t0 80%, before they lose capacity; once they reach ~50% capacity, wonky issues can occur.

Comment: _(Cont'd...)_ Generally, batteries can be found cheaper from seller's that aren't the OEM; the main thing to be aware of when not buying from the OEM is to ensure the battery comes with a 1yr warranty and is new, not used _(anything less indicates a subpar battery)_. I've had to replace my Alienware's battery a few times over the years and I always buy on eBay from sellers who are either a battery manufacturer or a reseller for a battery manufacturer _(I always ensure the OEM part # matches the third party and a 1yr warranty is provided by a trusted seller and have never had an issue)_

Comment: @JW0914 could there be any relationship with having secure boot disabled? Apart from that, it really draws my attention that the battery could be faulty, as the issue didn't appear with dual boot on the HDD I used to have. Maybe the fact that both OSs are stored on different units contributes to the cause?

Comment: Coincidence doesn't equal correlation - software & BIOS/UEFI firmware settings don't affect batteries or chargers in this way. It's unusual for a battery with 79% capacity to be failing - test with a known good battery to determine if the issue resolves. What could be occurring is one of the 18650 cells has failed/is failing _(e.g. cell(s) overheating, resulting in the firmware offlining the battery to protect hardware; if 18650's overheat, it doesn't always cause bulging and battery casements are completely sealed because if a cell leaks, and the electrolyte reaches air, it burns at ~2000F)_